# Running a script from inside a sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a simple gsheet I want to run a script inside so it can be run from Android mobile. Buttons and menus do not work on Android mobile.

- `C3` says choose your sort.
- `D3` has a data validation list of my sort scripts. Only 1 there right now. `NormalSort`.

I want `D3` to be blank and then I choose `NormalSort` from the drop down. Then `OnEdit` calls `NormalSort`. But it's not working.

In the script editor, `NormalSort` works fine on its own, but when in the sheet itself, the `onEdit` is not executing the `NormalSort` function when I clear `D3` and then choose `NormalSort` from my dropdown. I'm sure the code in the `onEdit` function is missing something. I get no errors. It just doesn't get to running `NormalSort`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getC3Notation() == 'D3') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}

function NormalSort() {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headerRows = 3; 
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: sortFirstAsc=true}, {column: 13, ascending: sortSecondAsc=false}]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to [Revision 4](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/104161/4)

The code has a "typo" maybe caused by a missconception about how Google Apps Script/JavaScript works:

There isn't a property named `getC3Notation` for the range class. The property name is [getA1Notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)

---

Partial answer to [Revision 1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/104161/1)

Looks that you are running onEdit from the run command on the Google Apps Script editor because in such cases the event object, e, is not defined.

In order to run onEdit from the Google Apps Editor for debbuging purposes, you have to create a an auxiliary function to create the event object and assign the required properties. For a broader explanation see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067/1595451) from Mogsdad to [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)

Comment: Yes you are right. When running it within the sheet it's not doing the sort it should or clearing D3. So need to figure out why.

Comment: Please update your question. I think that you should remove the error message and describe your test scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, on top of the getA1Notation error from the answer by @Rubén your onEdit function never calls NormalSort().  Change it to:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'D3') {
    NormalSort();
  }
}
```

For completeness, @Rubén stated [in his answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104216/81031) that there is a "typo" in the OP's code. That we need to use getA1Notation and not getC3Notation, which is not a valid Google Apps Script property of the range class.

Also note that the OP's use of the eval could work provided the item avulauted is the full ine needed to call the function, or `NormalSort();` which would probably entail adding "();" to the passed value.

Comment: @Rubén I called it a "getA1Notation error" and didn't know how to reference your post, which was already showing.  Good Team effort!  Note that the event() function COULD possibly work IF the cell contains the full line to parse function properly OR it is edited to add "();" to the end, making it "NormalSort();"

Comment: Ups, I think that I skipped the "on top...", I'm sorry. Regarding how to reference another post the best is to get the link through the "share" link just below the corresponding post (: Anyway, try to make your answers self-contained, in other words, include al the necessary information just in case the other post is deleted or unreachable for any other reason.